# Python - creating a logger if one doesn't exist

Tags: python, logging

Often I will use a log in python with the following setup:

```py
logging.basicConfig(
    format="(%(levelname)s) %(module)22s :  %(message)s",
    datefmt="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p",
    level=logging.INFO,
)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Sometimes I have a module `m.py` which can either be run by itself, or it can be called by another module.

If the module `m.py` is called as itself then I need all the setup outlined above, however, if `m.py` is called by a different module then the above isn't necessary, I can just have

```py
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and it will inherit the logger that was created in the script that called `m.py`.

What I would like to know, is how to I have a setup which will take into account both of these scenarios for the script `m.py`?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your problem is correct, you can use the `if (__name__ == "__main__"):` approach.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) is a question highlighting how this works.

So, for your problem, you could do:

```
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
  logging.basicConfig(
      format="(%(levelname)s) %(module)22s :  %(message)s",
      datefmt="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p",
      level=logging.INFO,
  )
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

This means the root configuration will run only if the module is called directly.